# Is there a way to set an overflow policy in Apache ActiveMQ?

Tags: activemq-classic, messaging

Is there a way in Apache ActiveMQ 5.x to specify what happens with messages, when the queue limit is reached? I am looking for something similar to TIBCO EMS's overflow policy, where you discard old messages to pick up new ones. The closest thing I found in the docs, was the Producer Flow Control to slow down producers.

Comment: It's not clear from your question which version of Apache ActiveMQ you're using, but if you're using ActiveMQ Artemis then check out the [address-full-policy address-setting](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/paging.html). It can be set to `PAGE`, `BLOCK`, or `FAIL`. The [ring queue](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ring-queues.html) functionality may also be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question isn't specific enough so hard to give concrete advice.  The ActiveMQ 5.x broker has [strategies](https://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling) for dealing with slow consumers or [fast producers](https://activemq.apache.org/scaling-the-depth-of-a-queue) but they depend a bit on the domain (Topic or Queue).

ActiveMQ Artemis has other features like [paging](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/paging.html) and other [strategies](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ring-queues.html) that can help.